# Is it possible to hide form field visible and hidden names as well as the form action from hackers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bots, spam

We've received an enormous amount of form submissions to our marketing automation platform. As long as the submitter has a properly-formatted email address, two hidden fields necessary to post to our server, and the form action address, they have all they need.

We've implemented every server-side validation tool available, but they're still getting through.

Is there a clever way to hide the information we store in hidden fields, and/or the form action address?

Comment: no.............

Comment: What about some captcha pictures ? Or encoded script, but any code encoding could be decoded.

Comment: There are ways to deal with spammers, but this question is too focused on a particular solution. There is no way to reliably identify who is a hacker and who is a legitimate user, so the line of enquiry you suggest (i.e. hiding things from spammers) is a no-go.

Comment: Captcha won't help when they're submitting from their own environment with the four items of info need to submit successfully. The 'hiding' idea came about when we considered changing the info that's apparently out there now.